# error in calling wsld through nodejs

Tags: node.js, wsdl, soapui

When i call it from soapui ,I am getting success response.
But when I am trying to call it from nodejs I am getting this error.

Unhandled rejection Error: a:InternalServiceFault: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Unhandled rejection I guess is regarding promises where you miss catch statement. Please provide more details as the above sentences are not really enough to figure out the issue can cause

Comment: Postman has a neat feature that will give you the code snippets in various languages of a given service call.   As mentioned by someUser,   More detail would be helpful though

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that the wsdl return an error, i am guessing that you probably sent a wrong request into the wsdl.

Please attached the 2 requests from your soup-ui and node js for us to be able to compare.